# Is there any OCR that can be trained for new symbols?

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, neural-network, ocr, fuzzy-logic

Is there any free/open source OCR available that can be trained for new symbols and can also output the coordinates of symbol found in the target image? I have read that tesseract OCR can be trained, but can it give me coordinates after OCR? any example? I need the code/steps to train a ocr using an image that contains one sybmol. There are around 20 symbols each in one image to be trained. and then use the trained OCR to detect those sybmols in the target image and if found, then give coordinates too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can train Tesseract to recognize new symbols. The hocr format contains the coordinates of the recognized words.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract

http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage#hocr-output

Comment: Do you have any more detail on this? The links are old/dead.